# How to check last accessed time about heap table (with no index)

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server versions 2008, 2012, 2017.

I can check the last accessed time of a table if the table has indexes.

However if the table doesn't have any indexes, how can I check the last accessed time?

Is it possible with a query?

Answer (score 0):

If the table in question has a column called eg. `TxDate` or any other name, you can run the following script to get your results:

```
select
max(TxDate) as [Date]
from  ['Your Table']
```

Just customize the above script to the column name in your table.

Let me know if it works.